# File Watcher using Windows Powershell to monitor multiple paths

Tags: powershell, file-watcher

I am building a File Watcher Powershell script to monitor multiple paths. I need to monitor around 6 paths using the same File Watcher script. I saw some script example on the net ('Powershell FileSystemWatcher for multiple paths) and have build a script. Following the script code:

```
$i=0 

# list of path of the monitored folders. 

$paths = Get-Content "D:\abc\Folder_monitored_paths.txt"; 

foreach ($path in $paths)  
{ 

$filter = '*.*'   

$fsw = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $path -Property @{IncludeSubdirectories = $true} 

Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Created -SourceIdentifier "$i+folderCreated" -Action { 

$name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name 
$changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType 
$fpath = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath 
$timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated 

$logline = "$(Get-Date), $changeType, $fpath, $name"
Add-content "D:\log.txt" -value $logline 


}

$i = $i+1 

}
```

I have placed around 3 paths in:     `$paths = Get-Content "D:\abc\Folder_monitored_paths.txt";`

On executing the code what happens is that the command prompt immediatly returns back on the output screen. After that when I place the files in all the 3 paths it logs the entry for all the 3 directories. On the second run when I places the files again in the directories then no entry gets logged in the log file. Why is this happening ? Why its not logging the entries the second time and also why the command prompt immediatly returns back ?  I something missing / wrong in the code ?

Not having any clue to my above 2 queries. Please kindly help.

Comment: What do you mean by this? 'On the second run', unless you unregistered the original event, it is still running.  Get-EventSubscriber -Force | Unregister-Event -Force  In testing what you have here, it works, from what I've tried here, as expected as long as you remove the previous registration before setting it again.

Comment: By 'On the second run' I mean that when I place the file the second time i.e. second file in each location .... It's not logging the event in the "log.txt" file. Also one more observation if the "log.txt" is not present in the location ... then its not creating one .. Also why the command prompt immediately return back and does not wait .. The main objective still remains that I have to monitor around 6 paths with the same FileWatcher script .... please advice.

Comment: That's not what I get on my side, I could post those results to show you. The prompt should come bac since this is a background thing, thus allowing you to do other work. If you want to know that the event is still active, just look it up --- Get-EventSubscriber -Force | Format-Table -AutoSize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the OP based on my last comment.

```
$i=0 

# list of path of the monitored folders. 

$paths = Get-Content "D:\temp\Folder_monitored_paths.txt" 

foreach ($path in $paths)  
{ 
    $filter = '*.*'   

    $fsw = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $path -Property @{IncludeSubdirectories = $true} 

    Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Created -SourceIdentifier "$i+folderCreated" `
    -Action { 
                $name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name 
                $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType 
                $fpath = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath 
                $timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated 

                $logline = "$(Get-Date), $changeType, $fpath, $name"
                Add-content "D:\temp\log.txt" -value $logline 
            }

    $i = $i+1 
}

<#
Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location             Command                  
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------             -------                  
1      0+folderCreated                 NotStarted    False                                 ...                     
2      1+folderCreated                 NotStarted    False                                 ...                     
3      2+folderCreated                 NotStarted    False                                 ... 
#>


Get-EventSubscriber -Force | Format-Table -AutoSize
<#
SubscriptionId SourceObject                EventName SourceIdentifier Action                                  HandlerDelegate SupportEvent ForwardEvent
-------------- ------------                --------- ---------------- ------                                  --------------- ------------ ------------
             1 System.IO.FileSystemWatcher Created   0+folderCreated  System.Management.Automation.PSEventJob                        False        False
             2 System.IO.FileSystemWatcher Created   1+folderCreated  System.Management.Automation.PSEventJob                        False        False
             3 System.IO.FileSystemWatcher Created   2+folderCreated  System.Management.Automation.PSEventJob                        False        False
#>

<#
11/20/2018 17:10:31, Created, d:\temp\abcpath0\New Text Document.txt, New Text Document.txt
11/20/2018 17:10:42, Created, d:\temp\abcpath1\New Text Document.txt, New Text Document.txt
11/20/2018 17:10:47, Created, d:\temp\abcpath2\New Text Document.txt, New Text Document.txt
11/20/2018 17:11:08, Created, d:\temp\abcpath0\New folder, New folder
11/20/2018 17:11:13, Created, d:\temp\abcpath1\New folder, New folder
11/20/2018 17:11:18, Created, d:\temp\abcpath2\New folder, New folder
11/20/2018 17:12:29, Created, d:\temp\abcpath0\New folder\New Text Document.txt, New folder\New Text Document.txt
11/20/2018 17:12:34, Created, d:\temp\abcpath1\New folder\New Text Document.txt, New folder\New Text Document.txt
11/20/2018 17:12:41, Created, d:\temp\abcpath2\New folder\New Text Document.txt, New folder\New Text Document.txt
11/20/2018 17:12:46, Created, d:\temp\abcpath0\New folder\New folder, New folder\New folder
11/20/2018 17:12:52, Created, d:\temp\abcpath1\New folder\New folder, New folder\New folder
11/20/2018 17:13:00, Created, d:\temp\abcpath2\New folder\New folder, New folder\New folder
11/20/2018 17:13:29, Created, d:\temp\abcpath0\New Rich Text Document.rtf, New Rich Text Document.rtf
11/20/2018 17:13:42, Created, d:\temp\abcpath1\New Rich Text Document.rtf, New Rich Text Document.rtf
11/20/2018 17:13:47, Created, d:\temp\abcpath2\New Rich Text Document.rtf, New Rich Text Document.rtf
11/21/2018 17:52:39, Created, d:\temp\abcpath0\New Microsoft Excel Worksheet.xlsx, New Microsoft Excel Worksheet.xlsx
11/21/2018 17:52:39, Created, d:\temp\abcpath0\~ew Microsoft Excel Worksheet.tmp, ~ew Microsoft Excel Worksheet.tmp
11/21/2018 17:52:39, Created, d:\temp\abcpath0\New Microsoft Excel Worksheet.xlsx~RF82e46c.TMP, New Microsoft Excel Worksheet.xlsx~RF82e46c.TMP
11/21/2018 17:52:45, Created, d:\temp\abcpath1\New Microsoft Excel Worksheet.xlsx, New Microsoft Excel Worksheet.xlsx
11/21/2018 17:52:48, Created, d:\temp\abcpath2\New Microsoft Excel Worksheet.xlsx, New Microsoft Excel Worksheet.xlsx
11/21/2018 17:52:56, Created, d:\temp\abcpath2\New Bitmap Image.bmp, New Bitmap Image.bmp
11/21/2018 17:53:03, Created, d:\temp\abcpath1\New Bitmap Image.bmp, New Bitmap Image.bmp
11/21/2018 17:53:05, Created, d:\temp\abcpath0\New Bitmap Image.bmp, New Bitmap Image.bmp
#>

Get-EventSubscriber -Force | Unregister-Event -Force
```

Comment: Thanks postanote ... actually I restarted the script and it solved the issue. Somehow it was giving the impression that its not polling the 3 folders. I also understand that the prompt is coming back as its a background issue. Thanks again.